# Google Mail doesn't download label as folder

Tags: iphone, ios, email, gmail, apns

I use GMail for push mail on my iPhone. I need that feature to sync my **contact, calendar and email** with Google. Setup is done using Microsoft Exchange following official tutorial from google at http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14252&answer=138740

The problem is, it seems the push mail downloads all of my labels on GMail, which is 200 labels, and it annoys me. (Screenshot below)

[image]

Is there any solution to remove that Label/Folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable these from your Gmail Preferences.

Go to Settings > Labels, and uncheck all the labels you don't wish to appear on your iPhone.  Once done, the iPhone should update accordingly.  If not, just delete the account and add it again.

For example, here are my settings:

[image]

Comment: did you mean remove the "Show in IMAP" checkbox?

Comment: @GusDeCooL: Yes, that's correct.  Uncheck anything you don't want to show.

Comment: not works, already try delete my account and adding it again. That only work if i using IMAP through "gmail" option setting on my iPhone. Notice i using option microsoft exchange here, i need use MS exchange because i want to sync my contact too.

Comment: Okay, I guess that doesn't work then. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using imap instead of MS exchange. It's quite possible to sync your contacts with Gmail. To do this:

1. connect your phone to itunes and select the "info" tab
2. Enable the "Sync Contacts" option.
3. Enable Sync Google Contacts and enter your google details.

Now you can change your gmail to imap as per the settings in sudo rm's answer.